# How i remove duplicacy from incoming dhcp packets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, dhcp, pyshark

what to do so it doesn't show duplicate entry until there is an update in mac or ip.
i want to print only when i got mentioned fields

````
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wlo2', bpf_filter='udp port 68')
capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=16)


fields = {}

for packet in capture:
    fields['mac'] = packet.dhcp.hw_mac_addr
    try:
        fields['vendor'] = packet.dhcp.option_vendor_class_id
        fields['h_name'] = packet.dhcp.option_hostname
        fields['ip'] = packet.dhcp.option_requested_ip_address
        fields['sub_mask'] = packet.dhcp.option_subnet_mask
        fields['server_ip'] = packet.dhcp.option_dhcp_server_id
        fields['domain_name'] = packet.option.dhcp.option_domain_name
        fields['dns'] = packet.dhcp.option_domain_name_server
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        print(packet.sniff_time, fields['mac'], fields['ip'], fields['h_name'], fields['vendor'])
    except KeyError:
        print('key not found')```

```key not found
2021-12-02 11:08:19.485258 34:1c:f0:6a:c9:00 192.168.1.5 M2006C3MII-Redmi9 android-dhcp-10
2021-12-02 11:25:19.461249 e0:13:b5:8f:xx:xx 192.168.1.5 vivo-1807 dhcpcd-8.1.0
2021-12-02 11:25:19.769917 e0:13:b5:8f:xx:xx 192.168.1.6 vivo-1807 dhcpcd-8.1.0
2021-12-02 11:26:44.359756 e0:13:b5:8f:xx:xx 192.168.1.6 vivo-1807 dhcpcd-8.1.0
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to deduplicate the packets yourself, i.e. by storing past packet ip/mac combinations in a set

````
fields = {}
already_seen_mac_ips = set() # set of (mac, ip) tuples
for packet in capture:
    fields['mac'] = packet.dhcp.hw_mac_addr
    try:
        fields['vendor'] = packet.dhcp.option_vendor_class_id
        fields['h_name'] = packet.dhcp.option_hostname
        fields['ip'] = packet.dhcp.option_requested_ip_address
        fields['sub_mask'] = packet.dhcp.option_subnet_mask
        fields['server_ip'] = packet.dhcp.option_dhcp_server_id
        fields['domain_name'] = packet.option.dhcp.option_domain_name
        fields['dns'] = packet.dhcp.option_domain_name_server
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        mac_ip = (fields['mac'], fields['ip'])
        if mac_ip not in already_seen_mac_ips:
            print(packet.sniff_time, fields['mac'], fields['ip'], fields['h_name'], fields['vendor'])
            already_seen_mac_ips.add(mac_ip)
    
    except KeyError:
        print('key not found')```
````

Comment: it's working, ty

Comment: But what if an ip will change of mac address, will it work?

Comment: an existing mac adress with a new ip will still result in a tuple that's not in the set -> the line will print

Comment: how can i add a counter on it like how much time i received a packet

Comment: use a `dict` instead of `set`

Comment: i defined empty dict and .update the mac_ip value in it, but it gives value error. can u share code how will i do that

Comment: `if mac_ip not in already_seen_mac_ips:
    already_seen_mac_ips[mac_ip] = 1
else:
  already_seen_mac_ips[mac_ip] += 1`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sipl/PycharmProjects/arpfind/arp1.py", line 28, in <module>
    already_seen_mac_ips.add[mac_ip] = 1
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Comment: this should've been a second question.... you need to replace `already_seen_mac_ips.add` with `already_seen_mac_ips[mac_ip] = 1`

Comment: Also there is some default in above ur answered code. It gives previous mac or ip if the mac or ip field isn't received in current packet @vinzBad

Comment: not giving any packet count @vinzBad

Comment: please post a new question